Merge 2 dictionary lists in order
I have these 2 lists of dictionaries:
[{'type': 'excel_macro', 'Name': 'Nuevo Diseño de Registro de nominas.xlsm'}, 
 {'type': 'pdf', 'Name': 'Presentación oferta comercial Nómina.pdf'}
]

[{'id': 35630898}, {'id': 35630899}]

and I want it to be like this:
[{'type': 'excel_macro', 'Name': 'Nuevo Diseño de Registro de nominas.xlsm', 'id': 35630898}, 
 {'type': 'pdf', 'Name': 'Presentación oferta comercial Nómina.pdf', 'id': 35630899}
]

That is, I want to merge the dictionaries of the lists in order, including the 'id' within the corresponding dictionary
I've looked for how to do it but I haven't found exactly this. I appreciate the help.

Use zip() to loop over the two lists in parallel. Use dict1+dict2 to merge two dictionaries. Put those together in a list comprehension and you have your solution.

@MarkTolonen Oops, right....

@MarkTolonen I intended that d1 and d2 were the list elements in the iteration, not the lists.

@MarkTolonen I know. I admitted that mistake.

Here's a way:
d1 = [{'type': 'excel_macro', 'Name': 'Nuevo Diseño de Registro de nominas.xlsm'}, {'type': 'pdf', 'Name': 'Presentación oferta comercial Nómina.pdf'}]
d2 = [{'id': 35630898}, {'id': 35630899}]

# union operator(|) supported for dicts as of Python 3.9.
result = [a | b for a, b in zip(d1, d2)]
print(result)

Output:
[{'type': 'excel_macro', 'Name': 'Nuevo Diseño de Registro de nominas.xlsm', 'id': 35630898}, {'type': 'pdf', 'Name': 'Presentación oferta comercial Nómina.pdf', 'id': 35630899}]


Ignoring that the items in the lists are dictionaries, the zip method will iterate through items in several sequences. Combining the dictionaries can be done using the unpacking operator (**).
a = [{'type': 'excel_macro', 'Name': 'Nuevo Diseño de Registro de nominas.xlsm'}, {'type': 'pdf', 'Name': 'Presentación oferta comercial Nómina.pdf'}]  
b = [{'id': 35630898}, {'id': 35630899}]

combined_list = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
  combined_list.append({**x, **y})

combined_list will be:
[{'type': 'excel_macro',
  'Name': 'Nuevo Diseño de Registro de nominas.xlsm',
  'id': 35630898},
 {'type': 'pdf',
  'Name': 'Presentación oferta comercial Nómina.pdf',
  'id': 35630899}]


Adding this answer for very complete context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python?rq=2
